# windows batch file: For L loop variable is not tracking

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I need to loop through a files with extensions 001 = 159. I have created a for /L loop to loop through this directory and set a variable. The problem is it won't set the variable so the program won't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
ECHO ON
SET LOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET LOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

chdir /d D:
SET /P practice="Enter Practice 3 letters "
SET String=%Practice%
CALL :UpCase String
SET String
echo String
pause
SET /P FileNumber="Enter Amount of files "


SET /P year="Enter Year "
SET /P typeSet="Enter 1-NoConvert 2-NeedConvert "
if %typeset% equ 1 set Type=NoConvert
if %typeset% equ 2 set Type=NeedConvert

set /P WaveType="Enter Wave Number "
set wave=Wave%waveType%Documents
echo FileNumber %FileNumber%
pause
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%FileNumber%) DO (
echo %%i
set Ext=_00%%i

pause

set src_folder=D:\
set index=Index_%String%_%year%_%type%_%Ext%.idx

echo indexFile %index%
echo %wave%

if not exist D:\ChartMaxx\%wave%\%String%_%year%_%type%_%Ext% mkdir 
D:\ChartMaxx\%wave%\%String%_%year%_%Type%_%Ext%
set dst_folder=D:\ChartMaxx\%wave%\%String%_%year%_%Type%_%Ext%


) 
@REM End For L Loop

:UpCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all UPPER CASE.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
FOR %%i IN ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" 
"k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" 
"w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%~i%%"
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: `SET LOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS` and `SET LOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` result in error messages on executing your batch file from within a command prompt window. The right command is `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`. Run in command prompt window `help` to get output the list of standard Windows commands. Run `set /?`, `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` to get output on one or more window pages the help for those 3 commands.

Comment: Instead of `SET /P typeSet="Enter 1-NoConvert 2-NeedConvert "` use the command line `choice /C 12 /N /M "Enter 1 for NoConvert or 2 for NeedConvert: "` and use on next line `if errorlevel 2 ( set "Type=NeedConvert"  ) else ( set "Type=NoConvert" )`. Run in command prompt window `choice /?` and `if /?` for help on those 2 commands.

Comment: In the __FOR__ loop you have to use `_!Ext:~-3!` instead of `%Ext%` to make use of delayed expansion required on defining/modifying an environment variable within a command block and additionally get always just the last 3 characters of the number to really get `001` to `159`. The command line `set Ext=_00%%i` must be modified to `set Ext=00%i`. That should be enough help for you to revise your entire batch code. Search on Stack Overflow with tag `[batch-file]` and additional word as everything you need to improve your batch code is written already thousands of times.

Comment: One last hint: You need `goto :EOF` after the closing `)` of the __FOR__ loop respectively after `@REM`  command to avoid a fall through to the subroutine after the loop finished. Run `goto /?` for help on this command.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I set the enabled commands like you said. That did not fix the issue unfortunately. The typeset is working so I am going to leave that alone. The for /L loop is still not passing the variable Ext.

Comment: Thank you after implementing all your changes it now works. I appreciate your help.

Comment: After more review the code still does not work. FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%FileNumber%) DO (
SET Ext=00%i
pause
set index=Index_%String%_%year%_%type%_!Ext:~-3!.idx
)

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%FileNumber%) DO (
    SET Ext=00%%i
    pause
    set index=Index_%String%_%year%_%type%_!Ext:~-3!.idx
)
```

Results: `set index=Index_GLP_2014_NeedConvert_!Ext:~-3!.idx`

The `_!Ext:~-3!` shows instead of `001`.

Comment: `set index=Index_GLP_2014_NeedConvert_!Ext:~-3!.idx` is output __before__ this already preprocessed command line is executed because `!Ext~-3!` is expanded __delayed__ on really executing next the command __set__. You can see that on inserting one more line with `echo !index!` or `set index` to see which value the variable `index` really have __after__ execution of command __set__.

Answer (score 0):

See how this works for you, *(I've removed some of the bloat)*.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /P "String=Enter Practice 3 letters "
CALL :UpCase String %String%

SET /P "FileNumber=Enter Amount of files "

SET /P "year=Enter Year "

CHOICE /C 12 /M "1. NoConvert, 2. NeedConvert"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (SET "Type=NeedConvert") ELSE SET "Type=NoConvert"

SET /P "WaveType=Enter Wave Number "
SET "wave=Wave%WaveType%Documents"

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%FileNumber%) DO (
    SET "Ext=_00%%i"
    SET "index=Index_%String%_%year%_%Type%_!Ext!.idx"
    SET "dst_folder=D:\ChartMaxx\%wave%\%String%_%year%_%Type%_!Ext!"
    IF NOT EXIST "!dst_folder!\" MD "!dst_folder!"
) 

EXIT/B

:UpCase
FOR %%i IN ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K"
    "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W"
    "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") DO SET "%1=!%1:%%~i!"
```

The only thing you may need to check/change is whether you need the additional **`_`** in front of the `Ext` variable; perhaps `SET "Ext=00%%i"` would fix that.

Comment: This worked awesome. I changed the exit/B to be inside the loop because the loop repeated itself when it got to the FileNumber. I spent 20 hours on this your help is appreciated.